# Convert jpeg using gamma correction in c++

Tags: c++, windows, image, opencv, imagemagick

I have an image img.jpg and I want to convert it to newImg.jpg using the linear gamma correction. I found out how I can do it using the terminal:

```
convert img.jpg -gamma valueOfgamma newImg.jpg
```

But now I want to do it in my C++ program. How can I do that using imagemagick++ or openCv?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't need some extremely portable, you can just call the `convert` utility from you C++ application

Comment: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/ very easy to port to C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [magick++](/questions/tagged/magick%2b%2b) you would use method `Magick::Image.gamma(const double)`.

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double valueOfgamma = 1.0;
    Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);

    // convert img.jpg -gamma valueOfgamma newImg.jpg
    Magick::Image image("img.jpg");
    image.gamma(valueOfgamma);
    image.write("newImg.jpg");

    return 0;
}
```