# Convert bmp to LINEAR jpeg in C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, imagemagick

I have a image.bmp and I want to convert it to img.jpg. But I want to be able to change the parameters of the jpg image, for example the gamma correction. How can I do this in C++, maybe using opencv or imagemagick ?

I already tried using the CImage class but when I convert the image from bmp to jpg it is too small(from 80MB to 2MB) and I lose a lot of information. So that is why I want to be able to control the parameters.

Thanks

Comment: See Eric's excellent answer, with code http://stackoverflow.com/a/39233320/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell so should I apply the gamma function on the bmp image and then write it as jpg ?

Comment: I presume so - I have no idea what your image looks like though, nor what you are trying to achieve nor why you think CImg isn't working...

Comment: CImage is working it just that I cannot control the parameters of the quality, gamma correction and so on. I don't have enough memory that is why I want to convert them to JPG, but I also don't want to lose a lot of information

Comment: @dasada You should transform `image` and save it to JPG after that. Check the code bellow.

Comment: Are they photos or graphics diagrams or what? BMP is a poor format - if graphics rather than photos, try PNG.

Comment: @Nikita I will try it out as soon as I will find a way to install ImageMagick :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is just a normal photo and I have to use BMP because I use a 3rd party library that uses only BMP

Comment: What OS are you using? And what camera takes 80MB pictures as BMPs (I am a photographer)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015, It's an industrial camera Optronis. I already downloaded the binary files and installed them. But I cannot include the header in the c++ program. I also added in additional include directories C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16\include but it says "cannot open source file Magick++.h"

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick has C++ API called [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/). Use `Magick::Image` class for picture manipulation, e.g. gamma correction can be done via `image.gamma(1.0);` method. Method `image.magick( "JPEG" )` will set output format to `JPEG`. For more details see [Image++](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/Image++.php) samples.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  Image image( "picture.bmp" );

  // Do your transformation on 'image' here      

  image.magick( "JPEG" ) 
  image.write( "converted.jpg" );

  return 0; 
}
```